# Error creating air native extension - output file is not writable

Tags: air, adobe, flash-builder, native

In an effort to learn how to create a native extension on my own, I've looked to the examples and help documentation from Adobe. I have actually created the required files for the extension (the native code, extension descriptor, the swc library and library.swf). However, when I run the command to build the .ane file I get this error:

> /Users/dalston/TeamAGC/sdk/4.6.0/bin/adt -package -target ane
>   ../release/DeviceInfoExtension.ane extension.xml -swc
>   DeviceInfoExtension.swc -platform iPhone-ARM library.swf
>   libDeviceInfo.a
>
> output file is not writable

I also tried a variation of that command that results in the same error (which comes straight from the Adobe help docs):

> /Users/dalston/TeamAGC/sdk/4.6.0/bin/adt -package -target ane
>   ../release/DeviceInfoExtension.ane extension.xml -swc
>   DeviceInfoExtension.swc -platform iPhone-ARM -C platform/ios .
>   -platform default -C platform/default library.swf
>
> output file is not writable

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Has anyone had this problem before? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Had the exact same problem, "output file is not writable"  and found solution.

In your case, change the

```
..release/DeviceInfoExtension.ane
```

to

```
DeviceInfoExtension.ane
```

Normally its the path where ANE is being placed that throws this error, so safest way is to run *name.ane* without any relative path indicators

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the folder ../release/ doesn't exist. I had this same error and it was just a silly mistake of specifying a non-existent output folder.